# The rank of the integral closure as a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $ O$ be a PID, and let $L$ be a finite separable extension of its quotient field $K$ with degree $n$. Prove that the integral closure of $O$ in the field $L$ is a free module of rank $n$.

Here is my idea:

Since the integral closure is a finitely generated, torsion- free, over a PID then it is a free module. Let $w_1,...,w_m$ the basis of integral closure, then $w_1,...,w_m$ are linearly independent over $O$ and we can prove that  $w_1,...,w_m$ are linearly independent over $K$.
  But how can i prove that  $w_1,...,w_m$ span every element of $L$ with coefficient of $K$, so  $w_1,...,w_m$ form a basis of $L/K$ therefore $m=n$?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do you know that the integral closure is finitely generated? It's true, but it requires a proof, which needs to use the separability hypothesis in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $K\otimes_OO'_L=L$, or if you don't like the tensor products, $S^{-1}O'_L=L$, where $S=O-\{0\}$. (Here $O'_L$ denotes the integral closure of $O$ in $L$.)
If $O'_L\simeq O^m$ as $O$-modules, then $L=S^{-1}O'_L\simeq S^{-1}O^m\simeq (S^{-1}O)^m=K^m$, so $m=n$.

Comment: thank you..it is clear..but why $ S^{-1}O^{'}_{L}=L $

Comment: @user196882 If $x\in L$, then $x$ is algebraic over $K$, so there is $a\in O$ such that $ax$ is integral over $O$.

Comment: Ok..and one more question @user26857 $ O $ is PID, why the set $S^{-1} $ (is that the multiplicative inverse of $S$ ??) is defined??

Comment: @user196882 $S^{-1}O$ is a notation for the ring of fractions of $O$ with respect to the multiplicative set $S$.

Comment: @user26857 sorry I really like this proof but I need to understand something: 1) It seems to me that if we chose $S=O_L'-\{0\}$ we would have got anyway that $L$ is isomorphic to $S^{-1}O'_L$, but it sounds strange to me. Where is the mistake?
2) Is there a short way to prove that $S^{-1}O^m$ is isomorphic to $(S^{-1}O)^m$? You can use tensor product and exact sequences if you want. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the integral closure of $O$. Take $z\in L$. Since finite extensions are algebraic, $z$ is algebraic over $K$. Therefore, there exists some $c\ne 0$ in $O$ such that $cz$ is integral over $A$, i.e. $cz \in B$. Since $B = \left\langle w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m \right\rangle$,
$$ cz = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i w_i \, , \text{ where } a_i \in O . $$
Therefore,
$$ z = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{a_i}{c} w_i .$$
So, $\{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m\}$ spans $L$ over $K$. Also, $\{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m\}$ is a linearly independent set over $K$. Hence, $m=n$.